# Xtube videos don't play on Debian

Tags: firefox, debian, flash

Youtube works fine, Xtube doesn't stream.  Not sure how I go about troubleshooting this, obviously flash is installed because Youtube works.

Using firefox 19.0.2 -- How can I check for upgrades to the flash player in debian?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out:  My version of firefox is ubuntuzilla, so these steps worked:

http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/ubuntuzilla/index.php?title=Ubuntuzilla_FAQ#Flash

- download the appropriate tar.gz from adobe:  http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/
- extract the libflashplayer.so from the archive and place it into ~/.mozilla/plugins directory ('~' means this is in your home directory).
- If the plugins directory does not exist in ~/.mozilla, which it doesn't by default, create it first.
- restart firefox, you should have flash up and running.

Apparently youtube works without flash now, it must rollover to HTML5 automatically if flash is not detected..?

Comment: please try your best to include the steps on the link **in your answer**. if the link ever gets broken, so does your whole answer.